# jquery load html when element is in viewpoint

Tags: javascript, jquery, viewport

Currently unable to get my code working using jquery.viewpoint.

```
$(window).bind("scroll", function(event) {
$('.port_holder:in-viewport').each(function(){
    var loaded=$(this).data('loaded');
    if(loaded==0)
    {
        var file_id=$(this).data('port_id');
        var file="html_includes/"+file_id+".html";
        $.get(file).success(function(s){
            $(this).html(s);
            $(this).data('loaded','1');
        });
    }
  });
});
```

The problem is with updating the necessary `.port_holder` div. There are 15 of these `div` holders and each one links to a specific external html file for it's content.

I have tried `$('.port_holder', this).html(s)` and `$(this, '.port_holder').html(s)`. Using just `.port_holder` fills all the elements with the html so I know it is connecting.

Once loaded I need to change the `data-loaded` element so that it does not keep on re loading if the user scrolls back and forward. Not sure whether there is a problem with my `$.get` syntax or whether the context of `this` is being lost somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

It was I expected, the context of `this` was not being passed to the success function therefore I used 'var that=this' and changed the lower bit to `$(that).html(s);`